# Как остановить действие скрипта через определенное время?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как остановить действие скрипта через определенное время?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class RoomSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Direction direction;

  public enum Direction
  {
    Top,
    Bottom,
    Left,
    Right,
    None
  }

  private RoomVariants variants;
  private int rand;
  private bool spawned = false;
  private float waitTime = 3f;

  private void Start()
  {
    variants = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Rooms").GetComponent<RoomVariants>();
    Destroy(gameObject, waitTime);
    Invoke("Spawn", 0.2f);
    StartCoroutine (walera());
  }
  public void Spawn()
  {
    if(!spawned)
    {
      if(direction == Direction.Top)
      {
        rand = Random.Range(0, variants.topRooms.Length);
        Instantiate(variants.topRooms[rand], transform.position, variants.topRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
      }
      else if(direction == Direction.Bottom)
      {
        rand = Random.Range(0, variants.bottomRooms.Length);
        Instantiate(variants.bottomRooms[rand], transform.position, variants.bottomRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
      }
      else if(direction == Direction.Right)
      {
        rand = Random.Range(0, variants.rightRooms.Length);
        Instantiate(variants.rightRooms[rand], transform.position, variants.rightRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
      }
      else if(direction == Direction.Left)
      {
        rand = Random.Range(0, variants.leftRooms.Length);
        Instantiate(variants.leftRooms[rand], transform.position, variants.leftRooms[rand].transform.rotation);
      }
      spawned = true;
    }
  }
  private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if(other.CompareTag("RoomPoint") && other.GetComponent<RoomSpawner>().spawned)
    {
      Destroy(gameObject);
    }
  }
  IEnumerator walera()
  {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    // Остановка скрипта
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете просто удалить скрипт и таким образом он больше не будет ничего делать. Вот пример как можно сделать:

```cs
private IEnumerator Stop()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
  Destroy(this);
}
```

Таким образом если вызвать корутину `Stop` то через `3` секунды экземпляр класса удалится с объекта. А если вам понадоьится еще один скрипт можно добавить его через `GameObject.AddComponent<YourScript>();`

Comment: Спасибо большое